# Passing data to component angular2

Tags: angular

Trying to pass data to a child component, I can attach the property into the template, but cant seem to access the id inside the class of the component. Any ideas?

---PARENT---

```
   <related-products [id]="product.id"></related-products>
```

--CHILD---

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams, Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {ProductService} from '../products/product.service.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'related-products',
  templateUrl: "wp-content/themes/f2/app/views/directives/related-products-template.html",
  inputs: ['id'],
  providers: [ProductService]
})
export class RelatedProductsComponent implements OnInit {

  products: any[];
  errorMessage: string; 
  id: number;

  constructor(
    private _service: ProductService,
    private _router: Router,
    private _routeParams: RouteParams
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.id);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `@Input` for the `id` property:

```
export class RelatedProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products: any[];
  errorMessage: string;   
  @Input() // <------------
  id: number;

  (...)
}
```

but it should work with the `inputs` attribute and you should have access to the value in the `ngOnInit` hook method. Are you sure that the provided expression `product.id` returns something defined?

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/aG4TdHbAls3cu04AAt64?p=preview.

Comment: I think its the fact that i am making a ajax call to get the data, and this inturn means the data is not ready in the child component yet. How do i wait for the child component to be built so i know the data is available

Comment: You get the product directly or it's an element within a loop?

Comment: Its the single detail page, so I make the call and get the data and I have the child component (Related Products( which needs the id from the parent component (Product Detail)

Comment: parents data is not ready when the child component fires. Need a way of accessing the parent data from the child component when the data is available

Comment: And you don't have any error on the `product.id` expression? ;-) I think that `product` is initially undefined. Perhaps the Elvis operator could help you: `product?.id`. The value will be received later. Try to display it in the sub component into the `ngOnChanges` hook method...

Comment: ngOnChanges this did the trick, this detects changes on the child component so it knows the data is ready